# How to add a date and print all results within a certain day?

Tags: php, sql, date, datetime

I think my question won't be any complicated for you, I'm just a noob. (however, trying hard to work on it)

I have a table in my .db and it looks like this:

| Number | Text | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31156 | abc | 11.01.2021 21:07:56 |
| 31155 | cba | 11.01.2021 21:07:56 |
| 31034 | def | 06.01.2021 20:16:40 |
| 30472 | ghi | 18.12.2020 20:55:45 |
| 30471 | ihg | 18.12.2020 20:55:45 |
| 30466 | jkl | 18.12.2020 19:29:24 |
| 30465 | lkj | 18.12.2020 19:29:24 |
| 30322 | mno | 14.12.2020 17:30:11 |
| 30303 | pqr | 12.12.2020 20:55:15 |
| 30302 | rqp | 12.12.2020 20:55:15 |

To print all results I use this code:

```
$Query = "SELECT LeagueLog.* 
FROM LeagueLog 
ORDER BY LeagueLog.Number DESC";

$Transaction = $db->query($Query);
if (empty($Transaction) == false){while ($row = $Transaction ->fetchArray()) {  

echo "<header class=\"contentItem__header\" style=border-top-color:#cbccce><a class=\"contentItem__header__wrapper\" ><div  class=\"contentItem__logo\" style=display:-webkit-inline-box;line-height:20px;color:#1d1e1f;font-weight:600;font-size:13px;width:75%>" .$row['Text'] . " (" .$row['DateTime'].")" . "</div><div  class=\"teamLogo--fancy\" style=background-color:#cbccce></div></a></header>\n"; /* The \n is for a new line in the HTML Code */
```

With this code I get all results in one column like this:

```
abc (11. 1. 2021)
cba (11. 1. 2021)
def (6. 1. 2021)
ghi (18. 12. 2020)
ihg (18. 12. 2020)
jkl (18. 12. 2020)
lkj (18. 12. 2020)
mno (14. 12. 2020)
pqr (12. 12. 2020)
rqp (12. 12. 2020)
```

However, I would like to have a Date and all results within the day. Something like this:

```
11. 1. 2021
abc
cba

6. 1. 2021
def

18. 12. 2020
ghi
ihg
jkl
lkj

14. 12. 2020
mno

12. 12. 2020
pqr
rqp
```

I really have no clue how to do this.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You have to write your own checks, to only echo the elements you want to echo.  Within your loop, check if the date has changed; if it has echo the `date` and the `text`, if it's the same as the last iteration, only echo the `text`.

Comment: Your results are not in a SQL result set format.  A result set has rows and columns.  All values in a column have the same type.  Strings and dates are not the same type.